# SQL - Locate end of Text (varchar) and append extra text to the end

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

What I want to achieve is be able to locate where the text ends and then add more text.

If I run my script, I can see my text length is 57 Characters.  I want to append more data at the end of the text.

```
select LEN(TXT1) AS COUNT, TXT1, TEXT_ID from HBM_TEXT where text_id=1584235430
-- 57 characters


COUNT   TXT1                                                    TEXT_ID
57  29-06-2017 - I need help adding a word to the end of this   1584235430
```

for example I now want to add `". 30-06-2017 - I found my answer"`
So the result would be

```
 "29-06-2017 - I need help adding a word to the end of this. 30-06-2017 - I found my answer"
```

I typically need to add the same text to multiple rows so the counts will be different on each record.

I can't see to get the update logic correct so any pointers are welcome.

thanks in advance

Comment: wont simple `+` operator work or you also can use `concat` which will take care of nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand correctly but what is wrong with following?

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(TXT1)+' '+CAST(DateVal AS VARCHAR)+' '+'Whatever' FROM YourTable
```

Or append whatever you want after `LTRIM(RTRIM(YourValue))` ??

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Imran, my update statement includes:

LTRIM(RTRIM(TXT1))+' '+ CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+' '+'29-06-2017 - My New Text Data'

I have my original text, line feed, new text.  It's works a treat.